# Struggling with adding or removing items to a custom Result<T> object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, entity-framework-core

This is driving me up the wall and even the tiniest nudge in the right direction would be so appreciated.

Basically this method is calling a third party API to get a list of bookings for a given user, which I want to then compare with a link table of booking IDs and member numbers to match with the loggedInMemberNumber that's being passed into the method and only return the bookings that were made by logged in user.

My issue is I'm lost with how to use the first response - the booking ids I want to create a list of are stored in response.Response.Data.Id but the  Result and Dto objects are modelled confusingly (to my admittedly inexperienced eyes!) and I can't work out how what I should add to the model to allow me to navigate it properly.

Intelisense can see response.Response.Data and response.Response.Included but there's no method to add or remove items. Do I have to add a custom class to the model to achieve this? How?

The Get:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBookingForUser(string policyNumber, string memberNumber, string loggedInMemberNumber)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policyNumber) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(memberNumber) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(loggedInMemberNumber))
        {
            var response = new Result<BookingListDto>();

            var getUserResponse = await _medicalSolutionsRepository.GetMedicalSolutionsUserIdOrRegisterUser(memberNumber, policyNumber, false);
            if (getUserResponse.Success)
            {
                response = await _medicalSolutionsRepository.GetBookingsForUser(getUserResponse.Response.UserId.ToString());

                if (!response.Success)
                {
                    return BadRequest(response);
                }

                var loggedInMemberBookings = _apiDbContext.MedicalSolutionsBookings;
                List<long> bookingIdsByLoggedInUser = new List<long>();

                foreach (var booking in loggedInMemberBookings)
                {
                    if (booking.MemberNumber == loggedInMemberNumber)
                    {
                        bookingIdsByLoggedInUser.Add(booking.BookingId);
                    }
                }

                //This is where I want to create an object to store the correct bookings from the original response
                Result<BookingListDto> correctBookings = new Result<BookingListDto>();

                foreach (var responseBookingData in response.Response.Data)
                {
                    foreach (var bookingId in bookingIdsByLoggedInUser)
                    {
                        if (responseBookingData.Id == bookingId)
                        {
                            //This is where I fall apart, Data has no method to add or remove items
                            correctBookings.Response.Data.Add(responseBookingData);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Included needs to be filled with these values also
                foreach (var responseBookingIncluded in response.Response.Included)
                {
                    foreach (var bookingId in bookingIdsByLoggedInUser)
                    {
                        if (responseBookingIncluded.Id == bookingId)
                        {
                           
                            correctBookings.Response.Data.Add(responseBookingIncluded);
                        }
                    }
                }

                response.Response.Data = correctBookings.Response.Data;
                response.Response.Included = correctBookings.Response.Included;
            }

            return ApiOk(response);
        }

        return ApiBadRequest("UserId is a required field");

    }
```

The Result model:

```
    public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("errors")]
    public IEnumerable<Error> Errors { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("first_error")]
    public Error FirstError => Errors?.FirstOrDefault();
    [JsonProperty("status_code")]
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    public Result()
    { }

    protected Result(bool success, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message = null) : this(success, statusCode, message, Enumerable.Empty<Error>()) { }

    protected Result(bool success, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message, IEnumerable<Error> errors)
    {
        Success = success;
        StatusCode = (int)statusCode;
        Message = message;
        Errors = errors ?? Enumerable.Empty<Error>();
    }

    public static Result Ok(HttpStatusCode statusCode) => new Result(true, statusCode);
    public static Result Ok(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message) => new Result(true, statusCode, message);
    public static Result Fail(HttpStatusCode statusCode) => new Result(false, statusCode);
    public static Result Fail(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message) => new Result(false, statusCode, message);
    public static Result Fail(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message, IEnumerable<Error> errors) => new Result(false, statusCode, message, errors);
}

public class Result<T> : Result
{
    public T Response { get; set; }

    //[JsonConstructor]
    public Result()
    {
        
    }

    protected Result(bool success, HttpStatusCode statusCode, T data) : this(success, statusCode, data, null) { }

    protected Result(bool success, HttpStatusCode statusCode, T data, string message) : this(success, statusCode, data, message, Enumerable.Empty<Error>()) { }

    protected Result(bool success, HttpStatusCode statusCode, T data, string message, IEnumerable<Error> errors) : base(success, statusCode, message, errors)
    {
        Response = data;
    }


    public static Result<T> Ok(T data, HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    {
        return new Result<T>(true, statusCode, data);
    }

    public static Result<T> Ok(T data, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
    {
        return new Result<T>(true, statusCode, data, message);
    }

    public new static Result<T> Fail(HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    {
        return new Result<T>(false, statusCode, default(T));
    }

    public static Result<T> Fail(T data, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
    {
        return new Result<T>(false, statusCode, data, message);
    }

    public static Result<T> Fail(string message, HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    {
        return new Result<T>(false, statusCode, default(T), message);
    }

    public static Result<T> Fail(string message, HttpStatusCode statusCode, IEnumerable<Error> errors)
    {
        return new Result<T>(false, statusCode, default(T), message, errors);
    }
}
```

The Dto model:

```
public partial class BookingListDto 
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public IEnumerable<Data> Data { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("included")]
    public IEnumerable<Included> Included { get; set; }
}
public partial class Included
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; } = "appointments";

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("attributes")]
    public IncludedAttributes Attributes { get; set; }

}

public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; } = "bookings";

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("attributes")]
    public Attributes Attributes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("relationships")]
    public Relationships Relationships { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your Data class does not implement any interface, such as `IList` that would provide such behavior, nor does it have any such methods anyway.

Comment: What does the json from the service you call look like? What do you want the json from your service to look like?

Comment: ps; one of the bonuses of having jsonProperty attributes is that you can dispense with these really bland/meaningless names for your properties and call them something that will help you understand the code, yet let the output json be suitably meaningless(kick the can down the road to the poor dev who has to consume it) - unless you're defining the json too in which case I recommend better names

Comment: Also; is the efcore tag relevant to this Q?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the problem you are working on, you will be well-served by learning about [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/). The examples I will give below are using the "extension method" version of this technology.

Assuming `_apiDbContext` is something like an Entity Framework database context, you should never do something like this:

```
var loggedInMemberBookings = _apiDbContext.MedicalSolutionsBookings;
List<long> bookingIdsByLoggedInUser = new List<long>();

foreach (var booking in loggedInMemberBookings)
{
    if (booking.MemberNumber == loggedInMemberNumber)
    {
        bookingIdsByLoggedInUser.Add(booking.BookingId);
    }
}
```

That will force the code to go through every row in the table. The proper way to do it is to use a LINQ query. For example:

```
var bookingIdsByLoggedInUser = _apiDbContext.MedicalSolutionsBookings
    .Where(row => row.MemberNumber == loggedInMemberNumber)
    .ToList();
```

This version uses the [LINQ `Where` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where?view=net-5.0), which will be converted to SQL including a proper `WHERE` clause by Entity Framework, and will be processed natively by the database. This can result in much better performance, especially for large tables. This also uses the [LINQ `ToList` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=net-5.0) to "materialize" the query into an in-memory list of items.

For the part where you are falling apart, there are a few issues. First thing is, the `Data` property of `BookingListDto` is an `IEnumerable`, which does not have an `Add` method. Second, the `Data` class used by `BookingListDto` is not the same as the class returned by the 3rd party API, so you will need to copy the data from the 3rd party response into your `Data` class. Finally, your `Result<>` class offers several [factory methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), which will be a cleaner way to create the result.

I think you will be better served by thinking in terms of creating a list of the items you want to return, creating the DTO from that, then using a factory method to create the result from that. So instead of:

```
            //This is where I want to create an object to store the correct bookings from the original response
            Result<BookingListDto> correctBookings = new Result<BookingListDto>();
            foreach (var responseBookingData in response.Response.Data)
            {
                foreach (var bookingId in bookingIdsByLoggedInUser)
                {
                    if (responseBookingData.Id == bookingId)
                    {
                        //This is where I fall apart, Data has no method to add or remove items
                        correctBookings.Response.Data.Add(responseBookingData);
                    }
                }
            }
```

You can use LINQ again to create the list of response items, then call the factory method to create the result, like this:

```
// first create the list of bookings to return
var bookings = response.Response.Data
    .Where(responseBookingData => bookingIdsByLoggedInUser.Any(id => id == responseBookingData.Id)
    .Select(responseBookingData => new Data { /* copy properties from resonseBookingData here */ })
    .ToList();
var dto = new BookingListDto { Data = bookings };
var response = Result<BookingListDto>.Ok(dto, HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

In addition to the `Where` and `ToList` operators, this uses the LINQ [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0) and [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0) operators.

Note that the `ToList` operator returns a `List<>`, which implements the `IEnumerable<>` interface and thus an be assigned to the `BookingListDto.Data` property.

Comment: I meant to get back to you at the time but the holidays intervened and I only got back onto this problem afterwards - your post helped greatly and thank you for your detailed response. I hope your 2021 is excellent :)